# Ubuntu 13.10 software raid

Tags: grub2, partitioning, system-installation, raid, mdadm

I had already Ubuntu OS installed on my desktop PC, where the software RAID 5 is configured ( 3 partitions /, swap and home ). This system was upgraded from the 11.04 till 13.04, it was quite messy, so I decided to install fresh system on existing partitions.

1st of all i found that there is no alternate version of the installer ( which i used to create previous installation ), so i stared with the regular image. I installed mdadm tools, assemble the partitions - fdisk are showing them properly - so i'm starting the installation - and everything i going fine until the GRUB instalation - this part fails - regardless of which partition i use as a target.

From the other hand, neither OpenSUse and Ubuntu 12.04 alternate does not have any problems with installing the GRUB - on this configuration, unfortunatelly Ubuntu 12.04 -> 12.10 upgrade is failing bacause of some Xorg issues ;(.

Maybe someone has an experience with installation of ubuntu 13.10 GRUB on the RAID 5 partitions - and could give me a hint, how to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance,
Piotr

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/367301/edit) and tell us what error-message you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install grub to the whole disk, not a partition.  Unity only allows you to select a single target to install grub to, so after installation you will want to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` where you can select all of the drives, so that if one fails, grub can boot from one of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:
[How to Install Ubuntu 14.04 with RAID 1 using desktop installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505446/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-with-raid-1-using-desktop-installer/505447#505447?newreg=6234fac7a5f640b4aaf18b54293c04c6)
It worked for me.

For those who want to use the RAID array only for storage (for example, only for the /home file), you can use the graphical installer, install GRUB on the device with / and the swap, provided this one is not a RAID array, and then do the chrooting, but without the GRUB stuff)