# How to Install Ubuntu 14.04 with RAID 1 using desktop installer?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid, mdadm, ubiquity

Many people claim that it is impossible to install Ubuntu onto RAID 1 with the Desktop CD. Is this really true? If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit: This guide does not take UEFI boot into account. Additional or different steps may be required if UEFI boot is desired. This guide assumes legacy boot!**

It is true, that the `ubiquity` installer does not know about `mdadm` software raid devices. Also it is true, that the live-cd is missing the `mdadm` raid administration tool. However, doing some work by hand, it is very much possible to install Ubuntu on RAID1.

In the following I will assume two identical hard disks (`/dev/sd[ab]`) which will be used completely for our new install. To simplify the recovery if one drive fails, there will be only one `mdadm`-volume `/dev/md0` which will then be partitioned for `/`, `swap` and data storage, e.g. `/home`.

After booting up the live-cd and (if necessary) configuring network access, open up a terminal and assume root access `sudo -s`

```
apt-get install mdadm
```

Now we create a single primary partition each of /dev/sda and /dev/sdb from sector 2048 to the end of the disk, for example using `sudo fdisk`. I also like to already set the partition type to `fd` for linux raid autodetection. The keystroke-sequence in `fdisk` (if the disk is emptyin the beginning, meaning no partitions) is `n <return> p <return> 1 <return> 2048 <return> <return> t <return> fd <return> w <return>`.

Now we create the `mdadm` volume:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --bitmap=internal --level=1 -n 2 /dev/sd[ab]1
```

I noticed, that the `ubiquity` installer also does not quite manage to create partitions inside this `/dev/md0`, so I also did this by hand - again using `fdisk`. So on `/dev/md0` create the following partitions:

- `/dev/md0p1` for your root filesystem, the size of course depending upon how much software you are going to install.
- `/dev/md0p2` for swap, the size of course also depending on what you use the machine for and how much ram it's got
- `/dev/md0p3` for /home, all the space that's left

After that we can begin the Installation. Make sure to start the installer from the terminal with the `-b` option, because installing the bootloader will fail anyway:

```
ubiquity -b
```

Make sure to go for manual partitioning and "use" the 3 partitions you just created and tick the `format` checkbox for `/` and `/home` so a filesystem will be created.

After the installation the system is not yet bootable, so do not restart the box right away. We need to `chroot` into the installed system and fixup some stuff:

```
sudo -s
mount /dev/md0p1 /mnt
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
cat /etc/resolv.conf >> /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /mnt
apt-get install mdadm
nano /etc/grub.d/10_linux  # change quick_boot to 0
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
update-grub
exit
```

Now the newly installed system is ready to boot. Have fun!

Comment: Will it ever be supported out of the box? Is there any reason not to offer this feature. In the perfect world there should be option for RAID install.

Comment: @Mwithii says: "The guide is ok, except for the "apt-get install mdadm" in chroot that was not working as is. I had to "cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf" to solve as described here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1268160&p=7960338#post7960338"

Comment: prob. easier to move the already-downloaded mdadm .deb from `/var/cache/apt/archives` into /mnt before `chroot`ing in, and `dpkg -i` to install it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to get Ubiquity to put a filesystem directly on an md device.  I don't particularly want to partition my md devices; I'd rather have multiple RAIDs for different filesystems.  That way I could potentially keep `/` and `/home` redundant with an old small drive, while `/data` where I put big files is degraded until I get around to getting a replacement that's as big as the original drives.  (semi-made-up example, various other scenarios should be obvious.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Copying only the mdadm deb is not enough, it needs to pull some dependencies. I really should have added something about `resolv.conf` to the original posting. Replacing it (like @Mwithii proposed) might break the automatic configuration by the `resolvconf` package. Better do the following: `cat /etc/resolv.conf >> /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If ubiquity won't put a filesystem there, it might work to do it manually before launching ubiquity. Otherwise creating one partition for the whole md is also a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: mdadm doesn't have any `depends:`, only `recommends:`.  I copy the .deb to my flash drive and install it (and smartmontools
) after booting a live CD/USB.

Comment: I wanted to test GRUB booting a filesystem on a RAID10,f2.  The extra hoop for GRUB to jump through of a partition on a RAID on a partition is a bit much.

Comment: @Sunday: good suggestion to try making filesystems first.  Ubiquity noticed that, and let me tell it to put / on the existing `md0` without partitioning it or even re-doing the `mkfs`.  (Which also allows using non-default options like `mkfs.xfs -m crc=1,finobt=1` that mkfs leaves off until kernel support for them has been around for years.)  Anyway, the install finished, but then `grub-install` failed.  Sorting that out now.

Comment: Grub install failed for me: `grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for RAID and LVM install.` Looks like boot parttition is missing? Maybe creating bios boot partition on both sda and sdb will help, like on http://serverfault.com/questions/386041/ubuntu-server-gpt-partition-table-mdadm-grub-boot-fail?

Comment: I followed this instructions and installed grub without errors. Everything went fine, but after reboot, there were no boot options. I was prompted with  BIOS with no boot options to choose from. The only difference in my case is that raid level is 0, not 1. @Sunday Any hints?

Comment: I did not have GPT/UEFI in mind when doing this. Maybe there are a few things that need to be adjusted, especially  considering boot loader installation. Maybe your system is in a state where it will only boot in the BIOS compatibility mode of your UEFI.

Comment: @Sunday: I was looking for the same solution as you, except I had an UEFI system. You are correct that a few tweaks were needed for UEFI (details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi]). Furthermore, I needed to insert a sleep in the local-premount scripts, otherwise I ended up at the grub rescue prompt when I disconnected one of my drives for testing! Does your solution work without a sleep if you unplug one of the disks?

Comment: @Sunday maybe, I am not familiar with it. I have Asus Zenbook and there are some UEFI related options in BIOS.

Comment: Your procedure worked for me with one modification. After starting the installer and configuring mount points, I would open a root shell and `chroot /target`. Then copy `mdadm.conf` from live system to installed system. After this I could proceed with the normal install, and even installing GRUB worked.

Comment: I am left with one problem though. During boot I get an error message saying `error: diskfilter writes are not supported.`

Comment: Ah, that was the `quick_boot` setting was for. Changing that to 0 and running `update-grub` fixed that problem for me.

Comment: Should same work for RAID0?

Comment: Propably. But I would leave the swap partition out of the raid0 and create two seperate swap partitions, because the kernel automatically does load-balancing between multiple swap spaces and this could give better performance than a single swapspace on a raid0.

Comment: @Sunday Looks like something has changed, and this instruction needs to be updated, after installing, I'm getting some errors. It still works, but would be good to have this fixed, I had troubles and unable to boot after few months. I would appreciate if you take a look at my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/766355/error-unknown-command-hwmatch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @umpirsky I added a warning to the guide. Please look into http://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi].

Comment: @Sunday Yes, I was kinda aware of this, but a year ago when I was installing 15.04, I created instruction https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/6ee1f870e759815333c8 which was combination of this 2, and was working perfectly. Now with 16.04 UbuntuGnome, I have this http://askubuntu.com/questions/766355/error-unknown-command-hwmatch problem. So I'm trying to identify what should I change in my gist or how to fix this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** install Ubuntu Desktop CD with RAID 1. My advice:

1. Use the Ubuntu Server CD to have a **guided** RAID 1 install. The manual for this is here (ignore the LVM part, not needed) :
   https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html
2. After that install the Ubuntu desktop environment with
   `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
3. Reboot and you have a Ubuntu desktop (installed with the server cd).

Comment: I think it is well known (and to be expected), that the server installer has RAID support. This question however was specifically about clarifying wether the desktop installer could be used anyhow. But thanks for letting us know anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried, but just came accross http://www.salamander-linux.com/.

Salamander is a modified version of the default installer for Ubuntu Linux, Ubiquity. This modified installer allows users to easily install Ubuntu Linux onto a Software RAID array. No special hardware is required -- the Salamander installer can be used on any system with multiple hard disks.

Comment: this seems pretty outdated from 2010.

Comment: @therealmarv Yes, must find new solution.

Comment: I think the overall better solution is to use a Ubuntu Server CD with very good RAID1 support and install everything like in the official docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html then at the end install `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and the server is also a desktop.

Comment: @therealmarv Maybe, but I read somewhere that there are some drawbacks with this approach. Desktop distribution is somehow different.