# How can I install Ubuntu onto a software RAID 10 array?

Tags: server, grub2, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I'm planning to set up a low-traffic server using RAID 10 with four disks.  I'd like to have Ubuntu 14.04 installed onto that RAID array.  I've seen plenty of guides explaining how to set up RAID 10 using `mdadm` with the OS on a separate disk from the array, but the only thing I've heard about putting the OS on that array is that it doesn't work because GRUB doesn't work on RAID 10 (that information was five years old).  How can I set up a system that has all of its data on the array?  I want to be able to run when any of those four drives fails.

Comment: I ended up using UEFI and GPT, and `dd`ing the `/boot` partition to each of the four drives.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an direct answer for your problem, but if your goal is to have the system run even when one drive fails, a raid 5 would do just that and give you more disk space.

Answer (score 0):

How does your system boot? Via EFI or MBR (CSM)? If the former, I can't see why you couldn't use my [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi), but create a RAID10 instead of RAID1 in steps 2+more. For maximum redundancy, I would clone the EFI boot partition to all four drives.

Comment: I was planning to use MBR, simply because I don't know of a reason to use EFI.

Comment: Actually, I'll need to use GPT because I'll have a 4 TB volume.  I guess I can still use BIOS, not UEFI, though?

Comment: If you're using GPT, I think UEFI is the better choice (some excellent info at http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html). Should you wish to stick with BIOS (a.k.a. CSM), you could check the first link in my guide (http://askubuntu.com/questions/505446/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-with-raid-1-using-desktop-installer).