# grub issues message at boot - "error - can't find command hwmatch"

Tags: grub2, uefi

This question [Error unknown command hwmatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766355/error-unknown-command-hwmatch) is exactly what I'm asking but was closed as non reproducible. Mine is very reproducible.

Ubuntu 18.04 freshly installed on a 64-bit UEFI machine. Default grub boot options work fine, but I wanted to add a brief countdown (my normal config).  After editing `/etc/default/grub` as normal and running `sudo update-grub`, the countdown works, but I get the error shown in the question title.

I tried the solution (copying files) in the closed question but it didn't seem to fit my configuration. Frankly I found the answer confusing.

I also tried editing `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` to comment out the IF-THEN structure that uses `hwmatch`. After that I did a `sudo update-grub` but I still got the error.

How can I get my countdown and not see this error?

Edit per comments -

Stock grub as installed (all non-commented-out lines shown)

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Edited grub to give countdown (all non-commented-out lines shown)

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us `cat /etc/default/grub`. Tell me what you edited/added to enable countdown.

Comment: Did you ever add an "insmod hwmatch" anywhere in the grub.d files?

Comment: @ubfan1 No, I didn't. Please elaborate.

Comment: @OrganicMarble show me the other grub lines that are not commented out.

Comment: hwmatch.mod is a module in the /boot/grub/i386-pc directory, and may need an explicit insmod somewhere before the use of hwmatch command in 10_linux.  Pick a location in the executation path (not in a function) before the hwmatch command to add insmod hwmatch..

Comment: @heynnema these are all the grub lines that are not commented out.

Comment: @ubfan1 my system doesn't have that directory. /boot/grub only has fonts, locale, and x86_64-efi sub-directories.

Comment: @OrganicMarble set `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and `sudo update-grub` and retry. If that doesn't help... on the outside chance... try `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` together, and `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @heynnema I'm willing to try...but how is that going to replace the missing module?

Comment: @heynnema that just gave me a much larger font reading of `error - can't find module hwmatch`

Comment: OK, I got it. Editing the 10_linux worked, but I made 10_linux_backup and that got incorporated into the cfg.  I made 10_linux_backup not executable and it's working now.

Comment: @OrganicMarble do you have a file /usr/gfxblacklist.txt?

Comment: The module `hmwatch` is part of the package `gub-pc` but not of `grub-efi`. Probably you should file a bug-report. For me your configuration works without error.

Comment: @mook765 I went to report it and found it had been done already: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560

Comment: @OrganicMarble I never heard back if you have the file `/usr/gfxblacklist.txt`, and if so, what its contents are.

Comment: @heynnema I'm happy with my fix for the problem and don't wish to investigate it further.

Comment: Seems also to be an issue with Ubuntu 20.04.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the error message, add this line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Source: [#4 comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560/comments/4) on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560

This will let a condition in the code get evaluated in such way that the codeblock referencing `hwmatch` gets bypassed.

As to how worrying is the missing command (or not): according to [mook765's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174374/grub-issues-message-at-boot-error-cant-find-command-hwmatch#comment1960128_1174374), it's part of only grub-pc, and not grub-efi, and is supposedly being referenced as a mistake in the case of a grub-efi install.

A voluntary remark on the countdown / menu:

Using

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

instead of

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
```

would make the menu visible (while leaving the countdown feature (at the bottom of the screen) and automatic fallback selection intact).

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after being done with the editing.

Comment: I'm switching the accept to this answer instead of mine because it's the superior approach. I'm not sure why you added the part about displaying the grub menu though, I don't want that. I just want the 5 second countdown, and my config gives me that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for the accept. I have applied updates :) (I left in a smoothened variant of the menu visibility remark because I think there's still a lot of people after that kind of information.)

Answer (score 2):

I commented out the if-then structure in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` that used hwmatch and that worked.

Note this was a Brute Force and Ignorance fix because I didn't know which of the outcomes in the if-then structure to choose. The one I chose worked for me, it may not for you.

After running `sudo update-grub` I got the desired result on boot.

```
# Use ELILO's generic "efifb" when it's known to be available.
# FIXME: We need an interface to select vesafb in case efifb can't be used.
if [ "x$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX" != x ] || [ "$gfxpayload_dynamic" = 0 ]; then
  echo "set linux_gfx_mode=$GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX"
else
  cat << EOF
if [ "\${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e \${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
#    if hwmatch \${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
#      if [ \${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
#      else
#        set linux_gfx_mode=text
#      fi
#    else
#      set linux_gfx_mode=text
#    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
EOF
fi
cat << EOF
export linux_gfx_mode
EOF
```

Note: at first this didn't work because I copied `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` to `/etc/grub.d/10_linux-backup` before editing it. But all executable files in `grub.d` get picked up so the original one got copied in too. I'm fortunate the system booted. I took the executable setting away from `/etc/grub.d/10_linux-backup`, re-ran `sudo update-grub`, and that did it.