# update to 19.10 caused boot error hwmatch

Tags: boot, 19.10

Yesterday I upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10. Today it doesnt boot correctly and shows this error.

```
error: can't find command `hwmatch`
error: Unknown TPM error.

Press any key to continue...
```

Pressing any key didnt bring me further. I had to press the power button for a few seconds. After turning it on again I see this:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System Setup
```

When I select Ubuntu I get those errors:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer.
```

After those errors I can login and work with Ubuntu.

Update: Commenting the lines of code described here [grub issues message at boot - "error - can't find command hwmatch"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174374/grub-issues-message-at-boot-error-cant-find-command-hwmatch) did not solve my problem.

Update:
I made a bootable usb with 19.10 to reinstall Ubuntu. Sadly after the install I got the same errors again.

Update: Flashing the BIOS of my Asus UX560QK to the newest available version 307 didnt work neither. I got the same result.

As you might have realized I am a beginner in Ubuntu. Any help would be appriciated!

Update: I managed to bypass this problem by disabling Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: I'm having the same boot issue with 19.10 having installed only 19.10. Looks like 19.10 isn't viable at this point. Any software testers available? My machine is old but has a UEFI BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grub issues message at boot - "error - can't find command hwmatch"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174374/grub-issues-message-at-boot-error-cant-find-command-hwmatch)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you for your recommendation. Actually I am not happy with this solution. In my opinion it is a workaround. This is the reason I did not post it as an answer.