# My laptop is acting Weird

Tags: boot, hardware, overheating

So I have lenovo thinkbook 14ml i3 10gen 8GB DDR4, 256 SSD, 1TB HHD.
When ever I bootup my laptop after say few hours of power off, it shows errors like.
Cant find command 'hwmatch',
A lot of secure boot forbid loading module,
And then unknown file system,
Alloc magic is broken at 0x(something, cant write this long) and then the laptop keep turning on and off.

But the weird part is if I heat my laptop up a bit by say charging it for 15-30 mins, the error is gone and laptop successfully boot up.

Any kind of answer would be great, I've no idea whats causing it and how to solve it.

Comment: Is laptop in a damp/high humidly area?  Sounds like a moisture problem if a bit of warmth fixes it.

Comment: No idea about the rest of them but I fixed the `hwmatch` thing with this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1174386/243321

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grub issues message at boot - "error - can't find command hwmatch"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174374/grub-issues-message-at-boot-error-cant-find-command-hwmatch)

Comment: Please disable Secure Boot and try again. Edit your question with updated information.

Comment: Would also check for slightly loose or maybe dust/dirt on connections.  The warmth might just tighten a connection enough.

Comment: @crip659 yeah its bit rainy here. , So if I get it open by some professional and get it cleaned once, it should work fine?

Comment: Would hope for a loose/dirty connection, moisture and computers don't mix well.  These are only guesses by me, and it could be software problem as some others suggested.

Comment: You mention it goes away if charge battery for about 30 min.  Does this only happen on battery power, or does it happen if on main power(plugged in)?  If only battery would suspect that is problem area.

Comment: @crip659 I can unplug the power cable after laptop turns on.. and the battery still works normally..

Comment: Asking if the problem only happens if you start up on battery, without being plugged into power.

Comment: @crip659 no, I can boot up just fine if its been booted up once and then shut down, within some time frame.