# My install of Ubuntu 20.10 is in a boot loop and I can’t fix it

Tags: boot, command-line, lightdm, 20.10, timeshift

My install of Ubuntu 20.10 is in a boot loop and I can’t fix it at all. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> work, but they just bring me to a blank screen with no text. I can’t even type.

I have a Timeshift backup of my system, but not being able to even get into the console makes it impossible to go back. This is probably because I was editing `lightdm.conf` before as well.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> gives me the usual `dev/sda2` text, but nothing brings me to the console where I could fix it.

If anyone can help that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

- First enter into the GRUB boot menu. Some say hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, but I can't seem to succeed with that. It might be something that *used to* work.

  What I do and almost always succeed with is hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> one time only, just as the BIOS displays its text.
- To get a root prompt, with the machine in a "sane" state, i.e. being able to run `apt-get` or `apt`, and most other commands, after getting to the GRUB menu, select an option that says *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and then select the latest kernel's *recovery mode*.

  In the recovery mode menu select these options:

  1. `fsck` - to have your file systems checked and mounted in writable mode.
  2. Enable networking, to be able to run `apt-get`.
  3. Drop to root prompt. Note that you need an extra <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  4. Undo the edits in `lightdm.conf` that broke your system.
  5. After you're done, type `reboot` or `shutdown --poweroff now`.

Comment: "and almost always succeed with [...] ESC": alternatively, one could set the grub menu to get exposed on every boot, along with a timeout of a few seconds, to let it pick the default entry on its own: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174374/grub-issues-message-at-boot-error-cant-find-command-hwmatch/1301092#1301092