# UNBUNTU 18.04 Login Loop

Tags: login

So basically my problem is that I'm in a a login loop and don't know what to do.
I tried to ask the internet and one solution was pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and than writing stuff but

if I press them there is only one line

```
"unbuntu: clean, 305096/2293760 files, 3928107/9175040 blocks"
```

after waiting it a line comes where it says
"ntpdate [20410]: no servers can be used exiting"

and than after some time it disappears and says
"Unbuntu 18.04.5 LTS susext-pc087 tty1
sunsext-pc087 login: "

so i guessed no I can login and do the stuff they made in the videos but no
after writing the username and than pressing enter it goes black and than it appears again

btw I don't understand much from computers so if you know how to help I would appreciate if you can explain it as easy as you can
or just write it in steps.

Comment: You need to try this - to get access to a "Terminal" -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1303506/289138 - as you're at the prompt; `dmesg | less` will launch the "less" text reader on the latest boot log, allowing to check what happened while booting. ` h` will bring up less's help - telling about key you can use to move about in the text view and the `/` -search option. Check after "failed" and "error" text, add info about what you find to your post above (use `edit`!).

Answer (score 0):

It happened something similar to me, it was because my desktop was uninstalled. If it appears your username as you were in the terminal, you could try

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I hope it works for you :)