# Input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1, /dev/nvme0n1: unrecognised disk label

Tags: partitioning, disk, nvme, disk-formatting

If someone can help me with this it would be much appreciated, cause I feel like I'm running out of options

Context: Roughly a month or so ago I built a new PC from scratch

| Properties |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Processor** | Ryzen 5 3600XT |
| **GPU** | Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 |
| **Motherboard** | ASRock B450M Pro4-F |
| **Memory** | 16GB (2x8) Kingston HyperX |

Drives:

- 250GB KINGSTON SA2000M8250G (nvme),
- 480GB ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi),
- PSU: Cooler Master MWE White 550

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 on the nvme drive with a zfs with encryption, added the SATA ssd to the pool for more storage, and had been using it without much issue.
Somewhere along the line I got my main drive corrupted (I assume because of shutting down incorrectly(forced reboot)), my system sometimes wouldn't even boot, othertimes I was able to login into the system and use it normally for about 3-5 minutes before everything but the mouse froze.
After trying to recover to no avail I swallowed it up, and did a fresh system installation, this time with just the regular recommended settings, all seemed to work fine.

I formatted by SATA drive to ext4, mounting to /drives/bigdrive, to hold larger files, like media and such, and made symlinks on the /home/$USER folder pointing to it, still working fine.
After installing some applications, I noticed the system didn`t have swap area, since I wanted the system to be able to sleep to conserve energy I tried creating some using gparted, setting it to a partition at the end of nvme0n1 and set the system to sleep after 1 hour of inactivity. I probably had done something wrong, because after waking up the system was very slow to respond, some applications were frozen, and the desktop screen was black. So I tried rebooting from GUI power options.

After booting I was greeted with the following screen:

```
error: can't find command `hwmatch'.
error: failure writing sector 0xb9dd800 to hd1

Press any key to continue..._
```

And so:

[image: Gparted screenshot I/O error]

So I tried, once again, to do a fresh installation, seeing as this time I probably wouldn't lose that much. But kept getting an I/O Error while trying to write on nvme0n1, so I did a live boot through the USB drive and opened gparted, and again, the same error, I couldn't format the drive, nor delete its partitions. I could format the SATA drive normally and create/remove partitions.

So I tried formatting the drive through the UEFI sanitization tool. Now the drive shows as unallocated, but again, same error while trying to create a partition table: I/O error.

Opening properties of the drive shows that it has an unrecognized disk label:

[image: Screenshot of info about unallocated]

These are the outputs of some of the commands I tried running:

fsck:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/nvme0n1
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

lsblk:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0     2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1     7:1    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop2     7:2    0 217.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop3     7:3    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop4     7:4    0  50.7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/481
loop5     7:5    0  30.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9721
sda       8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
sdb       8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1    8:17   1   3.8G  0 part /cdrom
nvme0n1 259:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
```

parted:

```
(parted) print all
Error: /dev/nvme0n1: unrecognised disk label
Model: KINGSTON SA2000M8250G (nvme)                                       
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: ATA KINGSTON SA400S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 480GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4028MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4028MB  4027MB  primary  fat16        boot, lba


(parted) rescue /dev/nvme0n1                                              
Error: /dev/nvme0n1: unrecognised disk label
(parted) mklabel gpt                                                      
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? Retry
(parted) rm /dev/nvme0n1                                                  
Error: Partition doesn't exist.
(parted) mktable                                                          
New disk label type? gpt
Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/nvme0n1
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? cancel
```

gdisk:

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 488397168 sectors, 232.9 GiB
Model: KINGSTON SA2000M8250G                   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 50E941E8-9C02-4264-99CE-C255291BC1A2
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 488397134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 488397101 sectors (232.9 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Comment: You can only do fsck on a formatted partition (not a drive) and it is for ext2, ext3, & ext4 family. Do not know zfs, but it would have its own tools. Label in this case is whether drive is gpt or 40 year old MBR(msdos). To create partitions you have to know or tell system to use gpt or MBR. Gparted defaults to MBR, but better to use gpt under select device. Setting label erases drive as all partitions are initialized. If gpt post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`

Comment: Sorry, I ran fsck out of habit, you're correct. I edited the question with the output of gdisk. It says it created new gpt entries, but in parted it still lists it as unrecognized label, and cannot mklabel. @oldfred

Comment: Regarding the error message `error: can't find command hwmatch`: it's coming from grub. It's normally exhibited by the grub-efi variant. If you are indeed booting with UEFI (and not legacy MBR), then (in normal circumstances) it can be largely ignored, and fixed for a cosmetic effect later, when you have sorted your disk out. See this thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/1301092/1157519

Comment: Now gdisk thinks it is blank drive, no partitions. Does testdisk show any old partitions?

Comment: `TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 238475 64 32
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

Bad GPT partition, invalid signature.
Trying alternate GPT
Bad GPT partition, invalid signature.










                P=Primary  D=Deleted
>[Quick Search]
                            Try to locate partition
`
@oldfred

Comment: And deeper search?

Comment: `TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 238475 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors















Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, Enter: to continue`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the drive is seated precisely as it should on the motherboard?  I have had strange things like this happen when memory chips, disk drive cables and power were not snug everywhere, but I am not sure about nvme are hooked up.  Check the manual with your nvme drive to make sure you haven't missed anything.

Either that, or possibly the drive is defective. Contact your vendor if it's under warranty still and ask for a replacement.