# I'm locked out of my pc

Tags: boot

I'm unable to login to my PC. I have an Acer TravelMate B1.
First of All I'm unable to bypass Grub 2.04.

After that it displays username and password but nothing worked. Every time I find something,it refers to changing via module(
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>
+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) but I can't even open the module.

I tried factory reset via alt but to no avail. I even can't open the boot to change that.I'mm literally stuck.I have read several articles but stumble upon the same problems every time.

This Shows UP when i give a username and password [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZafV.jpg) (failed to boot both the default and fallback items)
Then the Grub appears, but when i try advanced settings it asks again for the username and password.

Comment: I forgot to mention, i have a Ubuntu travelmate B1.

Comment: that image will not help much, with those "Dutch" errors.... (unless someone speaks Dutch )   What happens when you try to logon after it asks for you username (=gebruikersnaam) ?

Comment: I tried two of my username and even some Suggestions from some articles. IT results most of the time in. False:acces Denied.

Comment: Failed to boot both the default and fallback items. Followed UP by GNU-hub. Everytime i try to sellect something IT asks for my username and password

Comment: seems related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766355/error-unknown-command-hwmatch, but I cannot help further because the cause of this is unknown (to me)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, have a Nice day

Comment: @dennjz: please disable secure boot and boot again.

Comment: Thanks only hwmatch Shows UP now. Do you know i can fix this by any Chance

Comment: This Q&A gives the solution to the hwmatch error. https://askubuntu.com/q/1174374/243321 That message does not keep your computer from booting though. If your current situation is that your computer boots OK but you get that message, then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, but Everytime when i give my username and password It says that IT is wrong. What can i do about the username and password?

Comment: Please edit your question to succinctly and clearly describe your current problem.

Comment: From the moment that i start the PC. The first Thing that is displayed is the one from the photo above only the second fault message is gone. Apperantly this means that i can login. What ever i type in it gives me the message failed to boot both the default and fallback items.

Comment: Next Thing i know I'm greeted by the GNU-HUB. When i try the advanced option, it asks again for the username and password. Everytime i fill These in, it brings me back to th GNU hub. I've Read that you need to change this via terminal, but i can't open this at All. So i don't know to change the password and username

Comment: Please **edit your question**. Do not add information in comments.  Also, I've never heard of GNU-HUB. Do you mean grub?

Comment: Yes, it is Grub